# Use ARRAYFORMULA in a custom script function (Google Sheets + GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to adjust this function for use with `ARRAYFORMULA` in spreadsheets?

```
function SendTelegram(botSecret, chatId, body) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendMessage?text=" + encodeURIComponent(body) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
}
```

Instead of using a formula for each line like this:

```
=SendTelegram($H$1,$I$1,F2)
=SendTelegram($H$1,$I$1,F3)
=SendTelegram($H$1,$I$1,F4)
=SendTelegram($H$1,$I$1,F5)
```

By using this way:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SendTelegram($H$1,$I$1,F2:F))
```

Returns the following message:

```
Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length. (line 22).
```

Comment: Are you asking to modify it or asking how to use it?

Comment: [Guidelines for Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, you might have to adjust to the particular behavior you want.

```
function SendTelegram(botSecret, chatId, body) {
  if (body.map) { // is array?
  var response = body.map(function(b) {return SendTelegram(botSecret,chatId,b);});
   } else {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendMessage?text=" + encodeURIComponent(body) + "&chat_id=" + chatId + "&parse_mode=HTML");
  }
}
```